# How to hide/remove the presentation toolbar in the bottom of page in the jupyter notebook (v5.2.2)?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

After I updated to the latest version of Jupyter Notebook (v5.2.2), there is a "presentation" toolbar in the bottom of the page as below:
[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UToox.png). I googled a while, but it seems no one discussed about it. Is there any way to remove it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presentation toolbar can be a bit annoying when you don't need it. Here is what I came with to toggle it at runtime. Put the following code in one cell on your notebook and execute it whenever you want to hide or show the toolbar.

```
%%javascript
$('.nbp-app-bar').toggle()
```

This change is not permanent (does not survive a page reload), which is a good thing IMO.

Comment: That's nice, please accept the answer then it would help others.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `nbpresent`:

`conda remove nbpresent`

Then refresh your notebook page by `ctrl+shift+r` (refreshes stored cache in browser).

Comment: You can also simply disable the extension, rather than removing it. You can do it from the `Nbextensions` tab in the file navigator (this requires [nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions))

Comment: This also removes `nb_conda_kernel` which I guess many people would require.

Answer (score 6):

nbpresent can be disabled in the following way as [anaconda docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/use-jupyter-notebook-extensions#uninstalling-the-extensions) says:

`jupyter-nbextension disable nbpresent --py --sys-prefix
jupyter-serverextension disable nbpresent --py --sys-prefix`

It works on my jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on Mac from terminal

rm -r path_to_anaconda/pkgs/nbpresent*

in my case rm -r ~/anaconda3/pkgs/nbpresent*

Comment: It worked for me. I did the same as you said in your "solution", except I removed nbpresent from the terminal.